# Probability of the sum of the absolute value of 2 iid. standard normal random variables

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

$X$  and $Y$ are iid standard normal random variables.

I want to calculate: $P(2<|X|+|Y|<3)$.

I should integrate the joint pdf. over the neccessary area, but are there any easier ways to calculate it?

Comment: You could take a large sample and get a result just over $0.223$

Comment: @Henry Thanks but I want to calculate the precise value.